# replaceWith doesn't remove comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

I'm trying to replace a piece of HTML with jquery replaceWidth()

```
<!-- content box -->
<div id="content-box">
  yo
</div>
<!-- /content box -->
```

Like this:

```
$('#content-box').replaceWith(response.box);
```

But then I get

```
<!-- content box -->
<!-- content box -->
<div id="content-box">
  yo
</div>
<!-- /content box -->
<!-- /content box -->
```

Is there a way to make it replace the HTML comments too? :P

Comment: What us there in response.box?

Comment: its like the same html, but different text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the comments are outside `#content-box` div.

```
 <!-- content box : will not be replaced -->
 <div id="content-box">
    <!-- This comment will be replaced --> 
    yo                 
 </div>               
<!-- /content box : will not be replaced -->
```

Comments are not part of content-box. They are totally independent siblings. Not children. I guess the best way is to remove comments from its parent.

```
$('#content-box').parent().html('').append(response.box);
```

If you don't want to clear parent HTML, you can remove all comments from parent using the code below:

```
$('#content-box').parent().contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 8) {
        $(this).remove()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the comments **only within** the `response.box` (as I understood), you can use this:

```
$('#content-box').replaceWith(function(){
    return response.box.replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/ig, '');
});
```

The function above will change this:

```
<!-- content box -->
<div id="content-box">
    yo
</div>
<!-- /content box -->
```

into this (single comments):

```
<!-- content box -->
<div id="content-box">
    text from response.box
</div>
<!-- /content box -->
```